# Proof of a theorem on Reflection Groups

Tags: group-theory, reflection, coxeter-groups

I am reading the book *Finite Reflection Groups* by Grove and Benson.

I didn't understand the following proof. See $(a_1,t)$. *What is $t$ here?* Then Why the inequality $(r,t)-2(r,r_{i_1})(r_{i_1},t)<(r,t)?$ We know that $(r,r_{i_1})>0$, but it can happen that $(r_{i_1},t)<0$.

This means, the $t$ should be specified properly; is this correct?

OK, once we obtain $(a_1,t)<(r,t)$, and if $a_1\notin\Pi$, then we obtain $r_{i_2}\in \Pi$ and $a_2$ with $(a_2,t)<(a_1,t)$. Question is, here also, is $t$ arbitrary or it is chosen initially? I mean, does such $t$ exists?

> [image]

Comment: You are right; this $t$ has property that $(t,r_i)>0$; with this, now the proof is clear. I confused here because before this proposition, $t$ was not appearing explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently $(t,r_i)>0$ for all the simple roots $r_i$. In other words $t$ is some vector in the fundamental Weyl chamber.  May be $t$ is Grover&Benson's notation for the half-sum of positive roots? May be it is just a random vector in that chamber. After all, such a vector is selected so that using it we can define

- the *positive roots* as roots $r$ such that $(r,t)>0$, and
- the *simple roots* as those positive roots that cannot be written as a sum of two positive roots.

Anyway, the induction then works as described.

Comment: I promoted my comments to an answer as they seem to have clarified the issue the OP had.

Comment: Thanks, I in fact wanted to say you to put comments as answer; but you did it already. Thanks for clarification.